# Unable to reinstall ubuntu on Acer One Netbook (can't change boot sequence)

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux. I installed 12.04.1 onto my Acer One Netbook replacing Windows as my OS. After doing this I realised that I made a mistake in the partitioning and would like to reinstall Ubuntu as I can't make the changes I want to otherwise. The problem is that the Acer One BIOS is very basic and doesn't give the option of booting from CD. I have tried to reinstall by selecting wubi.exe on the CD, but get the following error:

```
Archive:  /media/Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS i386/wubi.exe
[/media/Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS i386/wubi.exe]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /media/Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS i386/wubi.exe or
          /media/Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS i386/wubi.exe.zip, and cannot find /media/Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS i386/wubi.exe.ZIP, period.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this up?

Comment: Wubi installs linux to a disk image - so, your windows install should be intact. You ought to be able to uninstall wubi from windows then reinstall

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop is able to boot a usb you can boot linux from a USB using UNetbootin (info [here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)), to install in a ubuntu machine just run in a terminal `sudo apt-get install unetbootin`. Then download a ISO and install it in your USB using this tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run `wubi.exe` from Linux. It's a Windows program that's designed to install Ubuntu from Windows (while Windows is running). When you run it from Linux you get that error as it defaults to treating it like a compressed zip file.

If you want to reinstall Ubuntu, you need to boot your computer from the USB or DVD and install that way.